# How can I start the PF service without interrupting existing connections?

Tags: freebsd, ansible, pf

I have an Ansible playbook that starts the PF firewall.  It freezes at this point because the SSH connection between the target and the host Ansible is executing on is interrupted as a result of this.  Is there a way to maintain this connection so that I can move on to the next task / playbook without having to rerun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. The module *service* breaks the Ansible ssh connection when starting or reloading *pf*. Please do not use it

```yaml
- service:
    name: pf
    state: started
    enabled: yes
```

Instead, use the module *shell* and let the command execute asynchronously. Set *pf_async_timeout* to your needs (~10 seconds should be fine. See the log below). For example, to start *pf*

```yaml
- name: start pf
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: >
      (( sleep 5; nohup service pf start 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ) & )
  async: "{{ pf_async_timeout }}"
  poll: 0
```

Put it into a handler. This way, it will be executed as the last task in a play. Because of the asynchronous execution, the task does not require the command to complete. The play will complete immediately. In the log on the remote host, you should see something similar to

```
Apr  5 09:19:33 plane ansible-async_wrapper.py[20170]: Invoked with 743252776472 45 /home/asadmin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1680679171.524129-1188854-111980374615608/AnsiballZ_command.py _
Apr  5 09:19:33 plane ansible-async_wrapper.py[20173]: Starting module and watcher
Apr  5 09:19:33 plane ansible-async_wrapper.py[20173]: Start watching 20174 (45)
Apr  5 09:19:33 plane ansible-async_wrapper.py[20174]: Start module (20174)
Apr  5 09:19:33 plane ansible-async_wrapper.py[20170]: Return async_wrapper task started.
Apr  5 09:19:35 plane ansible-async_wrapper.py[20174]: Module complete (20174)
Apr  5 09:19:38 plane ansible-async_wrapper.py[20173]: Done in kid B.
```

Create similar handlers also to stop and reload *pf*. To avoid troubles it is a good idea to configure and validate the configuration first and reload the firewall after the configuration was validated. See my role [freebsd_pf](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/freebsd_pf).

---

Example of the play

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook freebsd-pf.yml
   ...
TASK [vbotka.freebsd_pf : pfconf: Configure rules using server2-pf.conf.j2 template] *************************************************
changed: [plane]
   ...
RUNNING HANDLER [vbotka.freebsd_pf : reload pf] **************************************************************************************
changed: [plane]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
plane: ok=20   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=17   rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

If you want to proceed in the same play or playbook wait for the connection. For example,

```yaml
  ansible.builtin.wait_for:
    port: 22
    delay: 10
```

You can also wait explicitly for the completion of the asynchronous command. See [Asynchronous actions and polling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-actions-and-polling) and look for the module *async_status*.

---

Q: ***It hangs my connection asynchronously... that is, a bit later down in the Ansible playbook (a few seconds later).***

A: It is working for me. In the playbook, I wait for port 22 after *pf* was reloaded and [ping](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html#synopsis) the remote host a couple of times

```yaml
shell> cat freebsd-pf.yml
- hosts: plane
  become: true
  roles:
    - vbotka.freebsd_pf
  post_tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.wait_for:
        port: 22
        delay: 10
    - ping:
    - pause: seconds=5
    - ping:
    - pause: seconds=5
    - ping:
    - pause: seconds=5
    - ping:
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook freebsd-pf.yml
  ...
TASK [vbotka.freebsd_pf : pfconf: Configure rules using server2-pf.conf.j2 template] *************************************************
changed: [plane]

  ...

RUNNING HANDLER [vbotka.freebsd_pf : reload pf] **************************************************************************************
changed: [plane]

TASK [ansible.builtin.wait_for] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [plane]

TASK [ping] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [plane]

TASK [pause] *************************************************************************************************************************
Pausing for 5 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)
ok: [plane]

TASK [ping] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [plane]

TASK [pause] *************************************************************************************************************************
Pausing for 5 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)
ok: [plane]

TASK [ping] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [plane]

TASK [pause] *************************************************************************************************************************
Pausing for 5 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)
ok: [plane]

TASK [ping] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [plane]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
plane: ok=28   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=17   rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Example of the configuration

```yaml
---

pf_install: false
pf_enable: true
pf_debug: false
pf_blacklistd_enable: true
pf_fail2ban_enable: true
pf_sshguard_enable: true
pf_backup_conf: true

pfconf_only: false
pfconf_validate: true
pfconf_validate_command: "pfctl -n -f %s"

pf_type: server2
srv2_pss_ssh: "# pass in quick on $ext_if proto tcp from any to any port ssh flags S/SA keep state"
srv2_sshabuse: |-
  table <sshabuse> persist
  block in quick from <sshabuse>
  pass in quick on $ext_if proto tcp from any to any port ssh flags S/SA keep state \
       (max-src-conn 10, max-src-conn-rate 3/5, overload <sshabuse> flush)

pf_log_all_blocked: true
pf_ext_if: wlan0
pf_ext_tcp_ports: "ssh, smtp, domain, www, pop3, auth, https, pop3s, 5500, 8080, 8081"
pf_ext_udp_ports: "domain, snmp, prospero, 5500"
pf_dhcp_ports: "bootps, bootpc"
pf_jails_ip: "10.1.0.0/24"

# nfs
pf_nfs_tcp_ports: "sunrpc, nfsd-status nfsd, lockd, 815, 956"
pf_nfs_udp_ports: "sunrpc, nfsd-keepalive, nfsd, lockd, 815, 956"
pf_nfs_clients: "10.1.0.0/24"
pf_rpc_ports: "1286, 1283, 1229"

pf_reserved_internal_net: "172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16, 255.255.255.255/32"

pf_rules_custom:
  - dhcp_if="10.1.0.17"
  - ext_tcp_ports="{ {{ pf_ext_tcp_ports }} }"
  - ext_udp_ports="{ {{ pf_ext_udp_ports }} }"
  - dhcp_ports="{ {{ pf_dhcp_ports }} }"
  - jails_ip="{ {{ pf_jails_ip }} }"
  - nfs_clients="{ {{ pf_nfs_clients }} }"
  - nfs_tcp_ports="{ {{ pf_nfs_tcp_ports }} }"
  - nfs_udp_ports="{ {{ pf_nfs_udp_ports }} }"
  - rpc_ports="{ {{ pf_rpc_ports }} }"
  - syn_state="flags S/SA synproxy state"
  - sto_ext_ports="(max-src-conn-rate 500/10, overload <blocked_hosts> flush global)"
# DHCP
  - pass quick on $ext_if proto { tcp, udp } to $ext_if port $dhcp_ports
  - pass quick on $dhcp_if proto { tcp, udp } to $dhcp_if port $dhcp_ports
  # ext_tcp_ports
  - pass quick on $ext_if proto tcp to $ext_if port $ext_tcp_ports $syn_state $sto_ext_ports
  # ext_udp_ports
  - pass quick on $ext_if proto udp to $ext_if port $ext_udp_ports keep state $sto_ext_ports
  # nfs_clients nfs_ports
  - pass quick on $ext_if proto tcp from $nfs_clients to $ext_if port $nfs_tcp_ports keep state flags S/SA
  - pass quick on $ext_if proto udp from $nfs_clients to $ext_if port $nfs_udp_ports keep state
  - pass quick on $ext_if proto sctp from $nfs_clients to $ext_if keep state
  - pass quick on $ext_if proto { tcp, udp } from $nfs_clients to $ext_if port $rpc_ports keep state flags S/SA
  # jails_ip
  - pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to $jails_ip port $ext_tcp_ports $syn_state $sto_ext_ports
  - pass in on $ext_if proto udp to $jails_ip port $ext_udp_ports keep state $sto_ext_ports

pf_rules_nat:
  - nat on $ext_if inet from ! ($ext_if) to any -> ($ext_if)

# Howto: quick setup of jail on ZFS using ezjail with PF NAT/
# https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/howto-quick-setup-of-jail-on-zfs-using-ezjail-with-pf-nat.30063/
pf_rules_rdr:
  - rdr_jail_ports1="{ 80, 443 }"
  - rdr_jail_ports2="{ 80, 443 8080 8081 }"
  - rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 10.1.0.61 port $rdr_jail_ports2 -> 127.0.2.11  # test_11
  - rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 10.1.0.62 port $rdr_jail_ports1 -> 127.0.2.12  # test_12
  - rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 10.1.0.63 port $rdr_jail_ports1 -> 127.0.2.13  # test_13
  - rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 10.1.0.64 port $rdr_jail_ports1 -> 127.0.2.14  # test_14
  - rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 10.1.0.65 port $rdr_jail_ports1 -> 127.0.2.15  # test_15
  - rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 10.1.0.66 port $rdr_jail_ports1 -> 127.0.2.16  # test_16
  - rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 10.1.0.67 port $rdr_jail_ports1 -> 127.0.2.17  # test_17
  - rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 10.1.0.68 port $rdr_jail_ports1 -> 127.0.2.18  # test_18
  - rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 10.1.0.69 port $rdr_jail_ports1 -> 127.0.2.19  # test_19
  - rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 10.1.0.70 port $rdr_jail_ports1 -> 127.0.2.20  # test_20

# pf_ssh_whitelist:
# - 192.168.1.0/24
#
# NOTES: (1) nfs_ports: port 797 is needed for mountd;

# blacklistd
pf_blacklistd_flags: "-r"
pf_blacklistd_conf_remote: []
pf_blacklistd_conf_local:
  - {adr: ssh, type: stream, proto: "*", owner: "*", name: "*", nfail: "3", disable: 24h}
  - {adr: ftp, type: stream, proto: "*", owner: "*", name: "*", nfail: "3", disable: 24h}
  - {adr: smtp, type: stream, proto: "*", owner: "*", name: "*", nfail: "3", disable: 24h}
  - {adr: smtps, type: stream, proto: "*", owner: "*", name: "*", nfail: "3", disable: 24h}
  - {adr: submission, type: stream, proto: "*", owner: "*", name: "*", nfail: "3", disable: 24h}
  - {adr: "*", type: "*", proto: "*", owner: "*", name: "*", nfail: "3", disable: "60"}
pf_blacklistd_rcconf:
  - {regexp: blacklistd_flags, line: "{{ pf_blacklistd_flags }}"}

# EOF
...
```

Comment: After testing: It's the same result.  Only instead of hanging my connection as soon as I restart pf, it hangs my connection asynchronously... that is, a bit later down in the Ansible playbook (a few seconds later)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear this. I added a working example.

Comment: I think I was misleading with the question.  Since I connect to the same host that Ansible is running from via SSH, it is *that* connection that PF destroys when it starts (ssh to the control host).  Thanks for taking the time to post all that good info and the examples regardless.

Comment: OK. For the record. Set [*connection: local*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks) to execute tasks on the controller.

Comment: Actually I'm connecting to the controller remotely and when pf starts my ssh session from my house to the controller is cut off.  I found some examples for pf.conf that supposedly prevent that from happening, but so far no luck